# How do I record snow-based foley without real snow?

Tags: foley, snow, footsteps, post-production

At the time of recording, conditions were so severe on set that recording on-set foley was out of the question, much less getting clean dialog.  Lo and behold, it's now May, all the snow is gone, and I still don't have my footsteps in the snow.  I have some library effects, but I'd rather create my own.

I have heard that cornstarch makes decent snow sounds, as well as course sand.

What have you used to create snow-based foley effects without having the real stuff on hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the depth & form of the snow - nothing will replace the real thing, especially for deep snow... for footsteps & movement on 30 Days of Night we often used 3 layers: the initial impact was from rock salt that had been wet & left to dry so it formed a crust, then the deeper crunch was from a mix of rock salt & corn starch, plus the foley editor had a big library of real snow footsteps which he cut in sync with the foley performances... As it was summer in NZ when we worked on the project, we got a couple of sound recordists in Europe to go recording for us, which was essential especially for body falls & dragging etc...

Comment: I remember that.. very nice, icy sound to those footsteps.  Another method to add to the experimentation.

Comment: Love the rock salt technique, Tim, thanks for sharing that idea!

Comment: Indeed, very cool detail with the rock salt. Thanks for sharing -

Answer (score 8):

You're correct, corn starch is a tried-and-true substitute and has been used for years by many foley artists.

**UPDATE:** May I also suggest possibly contacting your local ice company? I have known of at least one film that took place almost entirely in the snow, and the foley artist arranged to have **LOTS** of real snow delivered to his stage for authenticity. May cost you a little more than the cornstarch but I'll bet you'd be much happier with the results, plus you get to build out your library with some great snow material.

Comment: That's what the SoundIdeas library said they did.. stage full of snow.  I wonder if they could get me a bag of ice chips/shavings that might sound okay.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 6):

+1: I've got a tiny ziplock of corn starch in a leather pouch, and just manipulating that sounds pretty good. Hands right in cornstarch works, too, but is messy. Depending on the scene, though, sweetening with styrofoam might add some icy-surface crunch if the snow's not recently fallen, or if the emotion demands a more aggressive sound.

[EDIT for the original poster: Photo below. I think the bag was originally from a wilderness signaling mirror, if I recall correctly. OK, it's, uh..."pleather," not leather, and yes, it looks like I'm smuggling contraband. But, *sniff*, no no it really works really, *sniff*, lifelike*VERY*lifelikeOhYeahOhYeah...*sniff*...]

[alt text http://www.noisejockey.net/stuff/cornstarchPouch.jpg](http://www.noisejockey.net/stuff/cornstarchPouch.jpg)

Comment: I've seen the "leather pouch" mentioned a few times.  I'm assuming that's a thin leather.  I just can't picture it sounding like snow, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: I just added a photo above to help illustrate this method!

Comment: Oh, and talk to Michael of Sepulchra.com - he's got a great post with snowy footfalls.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense with the picture.  I have something like that at home already, plus some.. uh.. cornstarch to put inside.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: The leather pouch that comes with Sony 7506 headphones would likely work really well for this.

Answer (score 2):

wildtrack foley? :)

Comment: I have a little bit of that, and that was my last resort.. thank you so much for the track you sent over!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm needing snow foley in spring too, and ended up filling a couple of balloons with corn starch. I've been able to get a variety of different snow qualities by varying the performance. It still doesn't have a true snow sound to me, but it's clean (so far), portable, and cheap.